# Why is XSPF Player not working on a Mac?

Tags: flash, macos, xspf

I'm using the [XSPF Player](http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/) (slim) on a new website. The client tells me they cannot hear any music on their Mac in Safari. The player is visible but it just says "Loading playlist..." and never continues past that point. I cannot imagine why since it works fine in all the PC-based browsers I have tried. I don't have a Mac so am having a hard time confirming this. I'm at a loss for fixing this issue and am wondering if someone else has had problems with the player on Macs before. The website is:

http://boernewineseller.com/

Maybe there is a security setting in Macs that don't allow it to download unknown extensions? The playlist is called [playlist.xspf](http://boernewineseller.com/resources/flash/music/playlist.xspf).

Note: I didn't even want music on the site, they rather insisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was simply a Flash security issue. The client was using www in front of the URL, I was not. Without a cross-domain policy set up Flash will not load something from a host. I've changed the path to the XSPF file to be relative and now it works regardless of the domain entered.

At some point I'll toss in a 301.

Answer (score 1):

First congrats on your valid XSPF file - few people get that right. I thought you might be interested that the player doesn't show up at my Firefox 3.0.5 on Windows. I had to dig into the HTML code to find the player URL. It worked fine when loaded directly. As I'm not on a Mac I cannot offer further help, though. Good luck.